# PHP Mysql why is it doing this? Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

So basically it goes in and finds a word in the database that matches with the word i type in and spits a reply out which works but it does all this other crap.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDA4R.png

This is my PHP Code

```
<?php
    // Connect to database
    mysql_connect("*****", "***", "****");
    mysql_select_db("***");

    // If something is received
    if($_POST)
    {
        if($_POST['action'] == "ask")
        {
            // Filter it to prevent SQL injections
            $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stringdata']);

            // Search it on the database
            $q = mysql_query("SELECT `reply` FROM `poka` WHERE `word` = '$text' ORDER BY RAND()");

            // Show result
            if($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
                echo $r['reply'];
            else
                echo "Cannot find a reply";
        }
        elseif($_POST['action'] == "teach")
        {
            // Filter it to prevent SQL injections
            $word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['word']);
            $answer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['answer']);

            // Insert it to the database
            if( mysql_query("INSERT INTO `poka` VALUES(NULL, '$word', '$answer')") )
                echo "ok";
            else
                echo "fail";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why does it spit out the other stuff??? did you look at the pic? It should only spit out the word "Hey" Not the other stuff

Comment: Can you check what's actually stored in your DB?

Comment: Looks like that is coming from the host your using, your code is fine, change hosts!

Comment: @ibash I always hate it when people are randomly injecting stuff in your pages, especially if that is one of the terms and conditions of your webhost, even more if you pay a lot of money for... oh, wait, never mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hosting company is automatically adding Google(?) Analytics code to every page sent. Talk to them.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following change, just to make sure you're not breaking any strings.

```
echo $r['reply'];
```

to

```
echo "{$r['reply']}";
```

Does it behave the same way anyway?

Although, the answer above probably is the reason.

Here is an example from [the PHP documentation on how to use arrays in echos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php):

```
// You can also use arrays
$baz = array("value" => "foo");

echo "this is {$baz['value']} !"; // this is foo !
```

Comment: This doesn't even echo any thing

Comment: Strange, it really should! See my revided answer for sources. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know definitively, head over to http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html and pick yourself up a copy of XAMPP.

With it you can quickly setup a local copy of a MYSQL database.  Migrate your database data over from your current host to duplicate the setup you already have.

Then in your PHP, change it to point to your new local database (on 'localhost') and see if you get the same result.

My suspicions are as everyone elses :)